Sharper segmentation SAM (Segment Anything)
I need to segment objects present on image like this:
Image 1
Image 2
I opted using Meta's AI SAM (Segment Anything) to crop out these objects.
My code looks like this:
import cv2
import numpy as np
import sys, os
from pathlib import Path
import torch
import supervision as sv
from segment_anything import sam_model_registry, SamAutomaticMaskGenerator, SamPredictor

# Get command line arguments
num = sys.argv[2]
img_path = sys.argv[1]
folder_path = sys.argv[3]

# Load the image from the given path
img = cv2.imread(img_path)

# Function to preprocess the image for cutting
def preprocess_image_cut(img):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    return gray

# Function to obtain a clean image
def get_clean_image(img, filter_level=1):
    gray = preprocess_image_cut(img)
    blurred_image = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
    _, binary_image = cv2.threshold(blurred_image, 210, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
    result_image = cv2.morphologyEx(binary_image, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
    result_image = cv2.medianBlur(result_image, filter_level)

    output_image = cv2.bitwise_or(gray, result_image)
    return output_image

# Function to set up the pipeline
def setup_pipeline():
    HOME = 'C:/'
    CHECKPOINT_PATH = os.path.join(HOME, 'weights', 'sam_vit_h_4b8939.pth')
    DEVICE = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
    MODEL_TYPE = "vit_h"
    
    sam = sam_model_registry[MODEL_TYPE](checkpoint=CHECKPOINT_PATH).to(device=DEVICE)
    mask_generator = SamAutomaticMaskGenerator(sam)
    return mask_generator

# Function to run the SAM model
def run_sam(mask_generator, clean_image):
    image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(clean_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(image_rgb, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    sam_result = mask_generator.generate(image_rgb)
    mask_annotator = sv.MaskAnnotator(color_lookup=sv.ColorLookup.INDEX)
    detections = sv.Detections.from_sam(sam_result=sam_result)

    annotated_image = mask_annotator.annotate(scene=image_bgr.copy(), detections=detections)

    masks = [mask['segmentation'] for mask in sorted(sam_result, key=lambda x: x['area', reverse=True])]
    return masks

# Set up the mask generator
mask_generator = setup_pipeline()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if img_path.endswith(".png"):
        save_path = folder_path
        os.makedirs(save_path, exist_ok=True)
        if os.path.isdir(f'{folder_path}/PROCESSED'):
            os.makedirs(f'{folder_path}/PROCESSED', exist_ok=True)
        img = cv2.imread(img_path)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        clean_image = get_clean_image(img, 3)

        print("Starting mask generation")
        masks = run_sam(mask_generator, clean_image)

        for i, mask in enumerate(masks):
            image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(clean_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            image_bgra = cv2.cvtColor(image_rgb, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGRA)
            extracted_region = np.zeros_like(image_bgra)
            extracted_region[mask] = image_bgra[mask]
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(mask.astype(np.uint8))
            extracted_region = extracted_region[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            extracted_region[:, :, 3] = (mask[y:y+h, x:x+w] > 0) * 255
            save_path2 = f'{folder_path}/PROCESSED/img_{x}_{y}_{w}_{h}.png'
            cv2.imwrite(save_path2, extracted_region)

    print("Finished")

But I'm struggling on some points like the fact that I don't want Sam to segment the numbers nor the lines that link the objects to the numbers.
Can someone offer any ideas about this topic? Also accepting other methods to segment the image.
